# How does breeding Alolan form Pokémon work?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

I'm curious how breeding in Pokémon Sun and Moon is affected by the new Alolan forms. Is the form randomly distributed based on the parents, like abilities or nature are?

For example, if I breed an Alolan Dugtrio with a standard Dugtrio, what is the probability that I will get an Alolan Diglett?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/alolaforms.shtml), you will hatch a Alolan form of whatever Pokémon you are breeding, *by default*, if there is one.

> When you transfer Pokémon from previous games and breed them, you will get their Alola Forms. However, if you attach an Everstone to the non-Gen VII native variant and breed, you'll get the standard form.

Thus, if you breed two standard Dugtrio, you will get an Alolan Diglett. The only way to *not* breed an Alolan form is to have the standard form parent hold an Everstone.

As mentioned in the comments, this means that breeding a standard form Pokémon with a Ditto holding an Everstone will still result in an Alolan form baby. In order to get a standard form baby with one of the parents being a Ditto is for the *non-Ditto* parent to hold the Everstone.

Comment: What about breeding with Ditto? If it holds the everstone what will you obtain?

Comment: @pinckerman If the Ditto holds the Everstone? "if you attach an Everstone to the non-Gen VII native variant and breed, you'll get the standard form" makes it sound like the everstone has to be held by the thing you want the standard form of, so having the Ditto hold it won't stop the baby from being the Alolan version.

Comment: Good to know, it will be difficult to pass the right Nature, otherwise.

Comment: @pinckerman I added a clarification to the answer based on this, thanks!

Comment: @pinckerman Assuming the Ditto has the right nature and the partner doesn't, you could use 2 Everstones to get a 50% shot at the right nature, preserving the form, then switch for Destiny Knot once you have a standard form with the right nature.